# SQL join same information from two tables using conditions

Tags: sql, join, plsql, left-join

I have one main table `t` with people characteristics to which I want to join information on birth dates from two other tables `m` and `n`, thus creating column `birth_date` in table `t`. The key variable I am joining on is `ID` which appears in all three tables.

The problem I have is that table `t` contains variable `age` and I want to join birth dates from table `m` **only if** `t.age < 18` and birth dates from table `n` **only if** `t.age >= 18`. 
What I have now is:

```
select t.*,
       m.birth_date as birth_date_1,
       n.birth_date as birth_date_2
from t
left join m
on (t.ID = m.ID and t.age < 18)
left join n
on (t.ID = n.ID and t.age >= 18);
```

This seems to work, however, I created two columns `birth_date_1` and `birth_date_2`. How can I do this within this one select to create only one column `birth_date`?

Comment: "do this within this one select to create only one column" is not clear. Every row to be selected from has certain columns with certain values. What do you want from such a row to end up in the result? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this within this one select to create only one column birth_date?

Since at most one of the left joins will succeed for each record in the source table, you can just use `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(m.birth_date, n.birth_date) as birth_date
from t
left join m on t.ID = m.ID and t.age < 18
left join n on t.ID = n.ID and t.age >= 18
```

Side note: parentheses around the join conditions are superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
SELECT
    [...],
    COALESCE(m.birth_date, n.birth_date) AS birth_date,
    [...]
```

Comment: And if I am already using coalesce for `m.birth_date`: `coalesce(m.birth_date_final, m.birth_date_orig) as birth_date_1`? Then can I use coalesce inside of another coalesce I suppose? `COALESCE(coalesce(m.birth_date_final, m.birth_date_orig), n.birth_date) AS birth_date`

Comment: Yes. Since `COALESCE` takes multiple parameters, you could even `COALESCE(m.birth_date_final, m.birth_date_orig, n.birth_date) AS birth_date`.